# How to add dictionary as an argument to unit-test function

Tags: python, flask, python-unittest

Hard to explain. I'm trying to pass on this dictionary to a final.html page, but when I run the test it displays "None:None" like it never got data from highscore dictionary:

```
  class FlaskTestCase(unittest.TestCase):

     highscore = {1:2}

     def test_initial_word(self):
        with app.app_context():
             response = self.app.get("/final", data = dict(self.highscore , user = "test", score = 12)) 
             self.assertIn("quick and easy game", str(response.data))
```

when I try other tests with variables only, it goes fine:

```
 def test_initial_word(self):#Check if game.html has been created
        with app.app_context():
            response = self.app.get("/rules", data = dict(user = "test", score = 12)) 
            self.assertIn("test", str(response.data))
```

How should I properly add dictionary to a test?

Answer (score 0):

`self.highscore` is not assigned to a key name. Did you mean to do:

`response = self.app.get("/final", data=dict(highscore=self.highscore, user="test", score=12))`